# PHPUnit - Assert trait method is called

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

Supposing I have a trait which currently has a method:

```
trait MyTrait
{
    public function traitMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now let's say this trait is used by several classes but I don't want to write a unit-test for every class.
Instead I want to write a single unit-test only for the trait:

```
public function testTraitMethod()
{
    $trait = $this->getMockForTrait(MyTrait::class);
    $this->assertTrue($trait->traitMethod());
}
```

But the problem is that a class may actually override trait's method:

```
class MyClass
{
    use MyTrait;

    public function traitMethod()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this case `MyClass` is doing something wrong but I'm not aware of it since I'm testing only the trait.

My idea would be write a single unit-test for every class just to check if it's using that trait and it's not overriding that method. If a class needs to override trait's method then it needs a specific unit-test as well.

Currently I'm writing unit-tests for each class that implements my trait but it's of course kind of copy-paste tests everywhere.

So is there a way to test if a class calls it's underlying trait method?

Comment: If your concern is the trait method being overridden and returning a different value, could you test `MyClass` and simply assert that the value from `traitMethod()` is as the trait should return it, rather than whether the actual method was called?

Comment: @benJ the thing is what I described here is just an example. In reality I have more complex stuff where I check if some methods are called on some mocks and if exceptions are handled properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using `Reflection`, I'll post it in case someone needs it because I couldn't find anything related to my problem. Feel free to comment or add different solutions if you want.

So the following test asserts that `$serviceClass` uses `$traitClass` and doesn't override methods declared in `$traitClass` except abstract ones and those which are manually added to `$overriddenMethods` array.

```
public function testServiceUsesTrait()
{
    $serviceClass = MyClass::class;
    $traitClass = MyTrait::class;

    $this->assertContains($traitClass, (new \ReflectionClass($serviceClass))->getTraitNames());

    $reflectedTrait = new \ReflectionClass($traitClass);
    $reflectedTraitFile = $reflectedTrait->getFileName();

    /**
     * If $serviceClass overrides some trait methods they
     * should be inserted into this array to avoid test failure.
     * Additional unit-tests should be written for overridden methods.
     */
    $overriddenMethods = [];

    foreach ($reflectedTrait->getMethods() as $traitMethod) {
        if ($traitMethod->isAbstract() || in_array($traitMethod->getName(), $overriddenMethods, true)) {
            continue;
        }
        $classMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($serviceClass, $traitMethod->getName());
        $this->assertSame($reflectedTraitFile, $classMethod->getFileName(), sprintf(
            'Trait method "%s" is overridden in class "%s" thus it must be excluded from this test.',
            $traitMethod->getName(), $serviceClass
        ));
    }
}
```

I also tried to compare declaring classes using `$classMethod->getDeclaringClass()` instead of comparing filenames but it didn't work: even if trait method is not overridden in class, `getDeclaringClass()` always returns the class itself.